# Github Actions $GITHUB_OUTPUT does not seem to be setting job output

Tags: github-actions

I have been using Github Actions to deploy changes for a data engineering project. I have been getting warnings that set-output command is deprecated and am attempting to use $GITHUB_OUTPUT but I am not able to set the output of the job using this.

```
if_merged:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
      name: check diff changed
      steps:
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            # Checkout as many commits as needed for the diff
            fetch-depth: 2
        
        - shell: pwsh
          id: check_file_changed
          run: |
            # Diff HEAD with the previous commit
            # filters out deleted files
            $diff = git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD
            
            # Check what files were in the diff
            echo $diff
            
            # Check if a file Pipfile.lock or Dockerfile has changed (added, modified, deleted)
            $BuildDiff = $diff | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Pipfile.lock' -or $_ -match 'Dockerfile'}
            $HasBuildDiff = $BuildDiff.Length -gt 0

            # Check if k8s job has changed
            $K8sDiff = $diff | Where-Object { $_ -match 'kubernetes_job.py'}
            $HasK8sDiff = $K8sDiff.Length -gt 0

            # Check if sql file has changed
            $SqlDiff = $diff | Where-Object { $_ -match '.sql'}
            $HasSqlDiff = $SqlDiff.Length -gt 0

            # Check if flow file has changed
            $FlowDiff = $diff | Where-Object { $_ -match 'flow.py'}
            $HasFlowDiff = $FlowDiff.Length -gt 0

            # Check value of matched object
            echo BuildDiff $BuildDiff ---
            echo K8sDiff $K8sDiff ---
            # echo DeploymentDiff $DeploymentDiff ---
            echo FlowDiff $FlowDiff ---

            # Set the outputs
            Write-Host "::set-output name=build_changed::$HasBuildDiff"
            Write-Host "::set-output name=k8s_changed::$HasK8sDiff"
            Write-Host "::set-output name=sql_changed::$HasSqlDiff"
            Write-Host "flow_changed=$HasFlowDiff" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            # Write-Host "::set-output name=flow_changed::$HasFlowDiff"
      outputs:
        build_changed: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.build_changed }}
        k8s_changed: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.k8s_changed }}
        sql_changed: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.sql_changed }}
        flow_changed: ${{ steps.check_file_changed.outputs.flow_changed }}
```

I commented out one portion of the Set the outputs step and updated it to $GITHUB_OUTPUT. However, when the job runs the flow_changed output is not set. I cant post images, but if I look at the complete job section after the action runs with $GITHUB_OUTPUT flow_changed is not set. It is set when I use the old set-output command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When [the runner is executing commands in PowerShell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell), you'll need to format the new output setting like this:

```
echo "flow_changed=$flow_changed" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Note the $env: that's missing from other examples.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set them like this:

```
echo "build_changed=$HasBuildDiff" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "k8s_changed=$HasK8sDiff" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "sql_changed=$HasSqlDiff" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "flow_changed=$HasFlowDiff" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

More information under https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs

Comment: Thank you for the response @jwpol. I just tested the action with those changes and I am not getting any output from the job. When I look at the complete job Evaluate and set job outputs is empty. I also moved the outputs section right after runs-on section but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: After testing it appears that $GITHUB_OUTPUT does not work for a powershell. I was able to set the output with bash

Comment: You can add and accept your own answer if you found a solution

Comment: it doesn't appear to set steps.step1.outputs.test for me https://github.com/tuxecure/clickable/actions/runs/3378555568/jobs/5608913658 am i missing something?

Comment: @Fuseteam if you look at the output $DOCKER_VERSION is empty. Where is that set? I know you can run docker -v to get the version, maybe try that?

Comment: @nac123456 nice sanity check, sadly that wasn't it https://github.com/tuxecure/clickable/actions/runs/3381097435/jobs/5614620600

Comment: @Fuseteam The last thing I would try is change docker-version to docker_version in the output step and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @nac123456 thanks but i feel like it has to do what this action doing in the background

Answer (score 0):

After testing I could not get powershell to set the outputs of the job so I wrote it in bash which worked for me.

```
# Diff HEAD with the previous commit
# filters out deleted files
git_diff=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD)
            
# Check what files were in the diff
echo "$git_diff"

# set output variables to false
flow_changed="False"
build_changed="False"
sql_changed="False"
k8s_changed="False"
            
for f in ${git_diff[@]};
do
    if [[ $f =~ "flow.py" ]]; then
         flow_changed="True"
    fi

    if [[ $f =~ "Dockerfile" ]] || [[ $f =~ "Pipfile.lock" ]]; then
         build_changed="True"
    fi

    if [[ $f =~ ".sql" ]]; then
         sql_changed="True"
    fi

    if [[ $f =~ "kubernetes_job.py" ]]; then
         k8s_changed="True"
    fi
done

# Set the outputs
echo "build_changed=$build_changed" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "k8s_changed=$k8s_changed" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "sql_changed=$sql_changed" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
echo "flow_changed=$flow_changed" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).